# What sort of promotions and/or sponsorships and/or other stuff would you guys like to see?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, sponsorship

This week, Ask Different is sponsoring the Daring Fireball RSS feed. This means Gruber will run a little ad for Ask Different in the [RSS feed](http://daringfireball.net/index.xml). I believe there will also be a plug live on the [Daring Fireball homepage](http://daringfireball.net/) on Friday, but don't quote me on that.

John Gruber is just one guy who likes to talk and write about Mac stuff on the internet. There are loads more out there. Stack Exchange has a budget to do this kind of sponsorship and promotion for the satellite sites, but we need you guys to tell us where it'd be best spent.

So! Help me help you help people on the internet figure out how to do cool stuff with Apple products, folks! Let me know what your ideas are.

Edit: I just want to clarify - we are not doing a Big Marketing And Sponsoring Stuff Push at this time. Ideas you guys post here will go in our back pocket and be trotted out one at a time now and then, when budgets and other resources allow. That said, I'm not just pretending to ask for suggestions so I can ignore them! Promise.

Comment: "John Gruber is just one guy who likes to talk and write about Mac stuff on the internet." If that isn't scholarly understatement, I don't know what is...

Comment: FWIW, I found out about and started participating in your site because you sponsored the Daring Fireball RSS feed. Whether you consider this a good or bad thing is, of course, another question.

Comment: I also found out about Ask Different and joined up because of reading about it on Daring Fireball.

Comment: @Wheat and Daniel - thanks for the notes! I'm glad you both found us.

Answer (score 5):

I would absolutely reach out to Dan Benjamin to see what his rates are for sponsoring some part of his podcasts. I am partial to build and analyze (or back to work) but I'm sure he and his staff could guide you to two or three shows that might be a good fit and be looking for episodes.  I'm ignorant of the costs involved, but perhaps hitting a few shows / weeks apart would be a nice spread out effort to raise awareness.

Comment: I agree 100%. And Stack Exchange has already reached out to him - Careers 2.0 has sponsored a few shows already. And with regard to the show that would be the best fit, I'd have to go with Hypercritical. It's for Mac alpha-geeks and got over 1M downloads for ep#27. B&A is great, but it's more for devs, and B2W is more about productivity than technology.

Comment: I looked into this and found out Ask Different actually did sponsor Hypercritical #27. (Did you guys know this and I just missed this? I'm neeeew.)

Comment: @Abby It looks like it was sponsored by Careers 2.0, not Ask Different: http://5by5.tv/hypercritical/27

Comment: @Kyle aha! I'll keep it in Ask Different's back pocket then.

Comment: @Kyle - awesome news - I mentioned B2W since I was thinking this site needs exposure to more consumers. Kind of like the people that walk into the average apple store. Moms and grandmothers. I'll have to ask my dad what he listens to - he hasn't taken my hints yet about self support. :-) Also, creative types like mike_ftw (twitter) and let's make mistakes might be worth targeting. (he reads sponsor names for $5 but will likely insult us so wear asbestos pants that day)

Comment: One benefit for B2W would be that Merlin typically goes off for a while about the sponsor, so it's more effective than Dan just reading the copy for 30 seconds. But I still think there's a lot of Apple nerds out there that either don't know about us or don't participate, and I'd like to see that change

Answer (score 2):

http://decknetwork.net/ might be more expensive than finding individual blogs for ad placement - perhaps you can have one buy there in wide rotation and select a few of the individual sites for a weekly spot.

It's top notch / fairly exclusive in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Ric Ford on http://macintouch.com has been covering Apple since the mid 90's and I'd put him up with [TidBITS](http://tidbits.com) which started in the late 80's for having a large proportion of people that have been around apple for quite some time.

http://www.macintouch.com/advertising.html